# What is the package-lock.json file for in Unity?

Tags: unity

My project contains this file:
Packages/packages-lock.json

And I'm curious about what it's for. It has a bunch of json about my packages in it, but it's not clear to me what goes in the lock file vrs the normal packages file.

Comment: The `package-lock.json` concept comes from npm. You can find plenty of info about this from a Google search; see for example https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html

Comment: @Kevin it looks to me like summarizing that doc could make for an upvote-worthy answer, if you're game to draft that up.

Comment: I found a article https://forum.unity.com/threads/packages-lock-json.912602/
You can check for the details and possible error

Answer (score 2):

`Packages` contains two files. The `manifest.json` file stores all the *direct* dependencies for your Unity project. For example:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "com.unity.modules.animation": "1.0.0",
        "com.unity.modules.assetbundle": "1.0.0",
        "com.unity.modules.audio": "1.0.0",
        ...
    }
```

When Unity resolves these it also needs to download other packages. The other `packages-lock.json` [file stores references to the specific versions of these *indirect* dependencies](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-conflicts-auto.html) required to support your dependencies.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.2d.animation": {
      "version": "4.2.6",
      "depth": 1,
      "source": "registry",
      "dependencies": {
        "com.unity.2d.common": "3.0.1",
        "com.unity.mathematics": "1.1.0",
        "com.unity.2d.sprite": "1.0.0",
        "com.unity.modules.animation": "1.0.0",
        "com.unity.modules.uielements": "1.0.0"
      },
      "url": "https://packages.unity.com"
    },
```

Since dependencies sometimes have their own dependencies, many of which are shared by other dependencies, [the `packages-lock.json` file resembles less a list of packages, and more a dependency graph](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-dependencies.html) (note the `depth` field below of this package, which is used by `animation`, which is used by the project:

```
"com.unity.mathematics": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "depth": 2,
  "source": "registry",
  "dependencies": {},
  "url": "https://packages.unity.com"
},
```

The `packages-lock.json` also saves the specific versions of all indirect dependencies regardless if one of the dependencies is update later on. This ensures you and your collaborators all see the exact same project, all the way down to the smallest packages.

> The Package Manager can only install one package version at a time, so
> it has to construct a dependency graph in order to determine which
> version of each package to install. When the Package Manager
> successfully resolves all version conflicts, it saves the resolution
> in a lock file to ensure determinism (so that the same packages are
> reliably installed every time), and to reduce the amount of time and
> resources it takes to compute the dependency graph again.

So, to summarize. You need both and should commit both to source control.

Comment: > So, to summarize. You need both and should commit both to source control.
Well, apparently not in a Unity context. As it seems, Unity ALWAYS recreates and overwrites this file, solely depending on the currently used Editor version, and the project's manifest.json. More importantly, it apparently ignores any specific versions in that file...
For example, switching between two different Editor versions such as 2021.2.11 and 2021.2.14 to and fro will happily downgrade and upgrade any dependencies listed in packages-lock.json, no matter what the version-controlled content of that file was.